# VI or LVE, answer is half a dozen

Tags: wordplay

The answer to this is half a dozen. I get that VI is 6, but LVE? How is that in any way a dozen?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Answer (score 8):

6 =

> .5 x 12 = Half of tweLVE = LVE

Comment: Please do not answer questions which are off-topic per our [attribution policy](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide); that policy is in place to prevent cheating and plagiarism.

Comment: @bobble what's off topic here is a matter of vote/consensus. Just because you personally take issue with a question doesn't mean it's officially off-topic and certainly doesn't warrant down-voting good-faith answers.